Actor Display Name: Azure DevOps Service
I am currently processing access level requests for my team, in relation to elevating and restricting access levels via the users tab. (All Requests come to myself)
When checking the audit logs, I am seeing the following details:

Authentication Mechanism: S2S_ServicePrincipal
UserAgent: VSServices (w3wp.exe) (Service=licenseprodukus)
Agent Displayname: Azure DevOps Service

I am enquiring is this something actioned by a user in Visual Studio? Or a possible postman API run?
Trying to establish who and what is changing the licensing when the team should be coming to a single source?
just my details in the audit log for licensing
